# How to show the integral of $x^p exp(-x^q)$ between $0$ and infinity converges?

Tags: real-analysis

How to show the integral of $x^p exp(-x^q)$ between $0$ and infinity converges? For p,q>0.

The function can't be integrated easily; so is there another way of showing this without having to evaluate the integral?

Comment: what are the conditions for $p$ and $q$? Anyway, you can use the squeeze theorem to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int^x_0 t^p / e^{-t^q} = \ell \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Correction: $t^p / e^{t^q}$

Comment: Sorry, now added conditions.

Comment: @MaR1oC , I guess I have to sandwich the integral between two other integrals between 0 and infinity that I know converge to a certain value??

Comment: Ok, so I can obviously use 0 as my lower bound, but struggling with an upper bound.

Comment: Try showing $\frac{x^p}{e^{x^q}} < \frac{1}{x^2}$ for large enough $x.$

Comment: calculate the outer integrals (pretty simple) and take the limit as $x \to \infty$ then they must converge to a number so the final integral also converges to that number but you can express it as an improper integral with $\int^\infty_0 f(t)dt = \lim_{x \to \infty} \int^x_0 f(t) dt = \ell$